# Is it possible for a Byakugan user to awaken the Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

Well... the title says it!

I ask this because, supposedly, Hyuuga and Uchiha are descendants of the Rikudou's eldest son (at least I am under that impression). In that way, does the Byakugan have any other special techniques that can be awakened (such as Tsukuyomi, Susano'o and Amaterasu in the Sharingan), and can it (ultimately) awaken the Rinnegan?

So far we have not seen techniques that derive from the Byakugan itself, but rather techniques that are possible because of it: the whole Hyuuga fighting style comes from the use of Byakugan, but it is not related to it in the same way that every Mangekyou technique is related to the Sharingan. They were only able to develop/and use it properly due to them having the Byakugan, but (again) it does not relate to it in the same way the Mangekyou relates to the Sharingan.

To sum up:
**Is it possible for a Byakugan user to awaken a Rinnegan?**

Comment: I don't think so. The Byakugan stems from a different bloodline than the Sharingan, so it doesn't seem likely that one's Byakugan could evolve into a Rinnegan.

Comment: I think it's tenseigan that can be achieved by a byakugan user which is almost equal to rinnegan in strength, but if a byakugan user can implant indra's and ashura's chakra, I think there's a probability to awaken the rinnegan. And with the byakugan, Kaguya's powers could be obtained.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unlikely.

While it is true that Kakashi originally said that the Uchiha clan (And the Sharingan) is a branch off the Hyuuga clan (and the Byakugan), <s>it was later revealed that it wasn't the case</s> **And even though Kaguya Otsutsuki was said to have the Byakugan**, it is currently presumed that the two bloodlines are separate and there's no actual connection between the two eye techniques..

No Byakugan upgrades were ever discussed/revealed, like you said, the Hyuuga specific techniques are only the Byakugan's potential being utilized.

#### SPOILER!

> **Moreover, it was revealed that the way to awaken the Rinnegan would be to combine Indra's and Ashura's chakra**, like Madara (who had Indra's chakra) implanted the flesh of Hashirama (who had Ashura's chakra), to bring out the Sage of Six Paths' chakra.
>
>  So theoretically, if Indra were to posses a Hyuuga clan member, and the identity of Ashura would be known, it may be possible. That, however, never happened and is not likely to happen in the future.

Comment: well the sage of the six path's mother had the byakugan... and since she was the first to eat the god fruit whose powers transferred to sage of the six paths, there could be a link drawn..

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that Kaguya Otsutsuki (mother of the Sage of six paths) was a Byakugan user. She could use Byakugan at a high level. Her son awakened the Rinnegan proving that Rinnegan is somehow related to Byakugan. Since the Sage of six path's elder son could use Sharingan it was also clear that Byakugan is the ancestor of Sharingan.

Comment: Note that she never possessed the Rinnegan.

Comment: Her third eye on her forehead is a rinnesharingan, which means its both the Sharingan and Rinnegan in one. The Byakugan is likely not directly related outside of the fact that all 3 eye types are Otsutsuki bloodline abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Rinnegan is not a state/technique like Mangekyou or Amaterasu. It's a whole different eye. Same goes for the Byakugan.

Regardless of there being a common heritage, the Byakugan is an innate skill like the Sharingan (the basic one). You have it because you were born in that clan. The Rinnegan is even rarer (being a supreme eye) but again, it's not a technique, it's an "eye" by itself.

So to answer your question, it's *highly unlikely* that a Byakugan user can awake the Rinnegan. I'd say **no**, but the Manga is not over yet and I don't want to bite off more than I can chew, but it wouldn't make sense because a Byakugan could develop a technique, at best, not an eye.

Comment: yet, a sharingan user can awaken the rinnegan (although it is an eye and not a technique).

Comment: @JNat Uhm I don't think I reached that part yet... Perhaps? Anyway, I suppose only in some special cases and not everyone, considering the Rinnegan power. :D

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the [**elder son**](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Indra_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) of the [**Sage of Six Paths**](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) had the Sharingan, introducing the Uchiha, but the [**younger one**](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Asura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki) didn't have any special abilities, introducing the Senju.

You need to have both Senju and Uchiha DNA to awaken the Rinnegan. During the battle with Hashirama at the 'Final Valley' Madara lost, but in the process he managed to get Hashirama's cells. He put Hashirama's cells into his own body, leading to the awakening of the Rinnegan. That's how Madara Uchiha awakened the Rinnegan. Nagato however did **NOT** awaken the Rinnegan, but when he was a baby, Madara transplanted his eyes into Nagato. Nagato was originally from the Uzumaki clan, and he had an extremely strong life force, as you can see due to his red hair, which eventually turned white because of the amount of power he had.

The Sharingan was supposed to originate from the Byakugan but then he writers must have just changed that idea and hoped everyone would forget. There are a few similarities between the Sharingan and the Byakugan, such as the ability to sense chakra. But I think the bonuses of the Byakugan are that you can see through objects, but if your especially skilled like Neji, or if you can focus enough like Hinata then you can even see a humans chakra points.

A Byakugan user can only awaken the Rinnegan if they posses both the cells of an Uchiha and a Senju inside them, and with time they would also probably be able to control the 'Gedo Statue'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to say that this is fact but here is a theory. Kaguya possesses two bloodline traits the byakugan and another sharingan/rinnegan trait. Upon having her two sons she could have passed the two traits down separately (seeing that we have not seen the sage's brother this is possible). This would mean that the sage obtained his mothers sharingan/rinnegan eye which manifested as the rinnegan without the sharingan tomoe. 
Upon the sage having his two sons he passed down his visual ability, albeit a weakened version (the sharingan), to his eldest and his physical energy to his youngest. It is, as we know, that only when senju and Uchiha blood mix do you acquire the rinnegan.
Pretty much what this theory states is that it is possible that the hyuuga clan originated from the sages brother while the rinnegan and sharingan originated from the sage himself. If this Is true then it would not be possible for the byakugan to develop into the rinnegan because they would belong to two different lineages. 
However this is just a theory so do not take this as fact.

Answer (score 1):

The byakugan might be able to awaken the the rinnegan. 
Kaguya otsutsuki passed down her power to her two sons. The sage of six path is the ancestor of the uchiha and senju inherited visual prowess and physical prowess. The sages brother is the ancestor of the hyuga and uzumaki inherited sealing justu and the byakugan. So the only way for a byakugan user to awaken the rinnegan is to implant uchiha and senji dna

Answer (score 0):

**No**
They can't. As you see, Kaguya had 2 sons: Hogoromo (Sage Of 6 Paths) and Hamura (the one with Bayakugan). While Rinnengan and Sharingan are totally different from Bayakugan. As both Sharingan and Rinnegan originate from [Rinne Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinne_Sharingan).

Answer (score 0):

### Kekkei Genkai

1. Bloodline limits that can be achieved if your Mom or Dad has these characteristics. It may or may not get activated.

   Examples are:

   - Sharingan was activated by Sasuke, while some Uchiha were not able to achieve it.
2. Bloodline limits could also be obtained randomly by a senju or family branch, like the Uzumaki clan, or just a random genius like the 4th Hokage who wasn't part of senju or Uchiha or any bloodline limit clan at all.

   Examples are:

   - Kimimaro is the sole user of the bone bloodline limit, which is an original from Kaguya.
   - Sage Mode - considered a bloodline limit which requires a person who has massive amount of chakra to perfectly control his chakra without using any amount of chakra to obtain the sage levels. For example, Minato, Naruto, Hashirama, ...
3. Bloodline limits can also be achieved through implants/mastery/intense practice but has a low chance of getting it into perfect use.

   Examples are:

   - Kakashi's Mangekyu
   - Kabuto's Sage Mode
   - Yamato's Mokuton

### Kekkei Tōta

An upgraded kekkei genkai or a 3-element bloodline limit user.

For examples:

- Rinnegan - an upgraded state of Sharingan
- Beast Bomb Rasenshuriken Jutsu - a densed Kyuubi, Sage, and Wind chakra
- Mokuton no Jutsu

Answer (score 0):

First of all they made it fair enough by make a new evolution of the byakugan which is TENSEIGAN that we saw in the seventh movie. They felt that the byakugan didn't get as much attention like the Sharingan.

I have two theories about this:

1. We all know that byakugan is related to sharingan due to the anime .. BUT noticing that kaguya the mother of SGO6P had the byakugan! meaning that byakugan came first - rinnegan - then sharingan .. so byakugan is the ancestor of the other dojutsu. This infers that Kaguya had the power of the jubi plus her byakugan as a result , she awakened one rinne sharingan in her forehead .in other words maybe if a hyuga becomes the ten tails Jinchuuriki he\she will also awaken one of two : regular rinnegan or rinne sharingan .

   Second theory is about bloods. We know that on one side the uzumaki clan are relatives of the senju , on another side the uchiha clan is descended from the hyuga clan . 
   so if a hyuga and an uzumaki/senju were to have offsprings , theyll perhaps have the power of the sage of the six paths ! which means theyll awaken the rinnegan .. (for example himawari , lets see what future hides)
   hope u like it  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how Kaguya possesses both the rinne sharingan, which is the progenitor of the rinnegan, and the byakugan it is within the realm of possibilities that a byakugan user may awaken the rinnegan, but as a forehead third eye since they already have byakugan in both eyes and the original source of rinne and tensei chakra is Kaguya herself. But I would imagine that only select Hyuga or Moon Shinobi Otsutsuki clan members can do this depending on the purity of their blood that match either of Hamura's aspects (Hyuga or Moon Shinobi Otsutsuki) and/or whether or not Hamura's children have unique chakra like Indra and Asura that makeup the chakra of their parent and only them and their transmigrants can awaken the rinnegan/ rinne sharingan. This is an hypothetical conjecture since what you're asking has remained unanswered at the end of the Naruto series.

In an hypothetical scenario, it may be possible for an eligible Hyuga clan member to acquire Asura & Indra's chakra or chakra from Hagoromo himself and they may acquire a single forhead rinnegan. For the sake of logistics, lets say they acquire one purple rinnegan in their forehead. Why? Because there may be a component in Hamura's chakra that may mutate the rinnegan into the rinne sharingan and thus since we are talking about one third of said chakra they may acquire an incomplete rinne sharingan. For simplicity's sake let's say that an eligible Hyuga clan member can acquire a purple rinnegan and that an eligible Moon Shinobi Otsutsuki clan member can acquire a red rinnegan. When that missing 1/4th is acquired this may trigger the third eye to transform into its complete form, the rinne sharingan.

This hypothesis may connect with another hypothesis as to why Kaguya doesn't appear to have the tenseigan while Hamura has it. Perhaps by acquiring Hamura's chakra and the tenseigan and then acquiring the rinne aspect that the user previously lacked, said individual may awaken the third eye as the complete rinne sharingan, but as a consequence of its activation the tenseigan deactivates, because the tensei chakra now has a rinnegan to be processed by and thus in the absence of rinne chakra and the rinnegan the tensei chakra manifests as the tenseigan in the user's byakugan. This maybe the reason why Kaguya appears to lack the tenseigan while his son doesn't. I would also like to add that Kaguya's byakugan is considered a kekkei mora rather than a kekkei genkai and it may very well be for this reason. This is taking into account that Hagormo and Hamura each hold an aspect of Kaguya's chakra in their own and if both chakra were to merge, her chakra may likely mainfest in the individual. As already mentioned, Asura + Indra = Hagoromo as shown by Madara and unspecified Hyuga + unspecified Moon Shinobi Otsutsuki = Hamura as demonstrated by Toneri. So why wouldn't Hagoromo + Hamura = Kaguya? Let's also take into account that Hagoromo's rinnegan are purple and tomoeless while his mother's rinnegan is red and with (9) tomoe like the sharingan. The absence of the tensei component in Hagoromo may be the reason why there is a difference between his eyes and his mother's eye.

A possible counter arguement for this last paragraph would be that Kaguya can indeed activate the tenseigan and there is no relationship between the tenseigan and her rinne sharingan as explained above. She may have simply chosen not activate them during her fight with Naruto and Sasuke. It can be further argued that her tenseigan may be more advanced compared to her son's seeing as how her son's tenseigan seems to be able to evolve further by sealing other clan member's byakugan inside it. Being the source of all chakra her tenseigan could very well be more advance than her son's. However, this hypothesis is also debatable as there is no evidence that supports that she has the tenseigan.

Hope that this explaination makes sense and even if there is something that you may disagree with or that you don't like, because it's speculative in nature that at least this attempt of explaining an untestible unknown (until Kishi gets off his ass and tell us the answer) may get your imagination going so you may actually formulate your own explainations on this matter.

Answer (score -1):

The byakugan was inherited from kaguya by her son hamura, while the constituent dojutsu that comprise the rinne-sharingan were inherited by hagoromo(sage of six paths), and as such, the byakugan cannot be transformed into the rinnegan, as its chakra constituents are totally separate. The byakugan can evolve he wever into the tenseigan, which exhibits similar abilities to the rinnegan, such as attractive and repulsive forces and truthseeker balls. In conclusion, the only way for a byakugan user to get the Rinnegan is by transplanting one and they must have massive chairs reserves and share even small relations to the senju, the uchiha or the uzimaki.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with that. In the anime, Hagaromo and Hamura, both have Byakugan at first. Then Hagaromo gets the Sharingan and later, the Rinnegan.