# Why doesn't the Byakugan have a second stage?

Tags: naruto

The Uchiha Clan had the Sharingan which  has a lot  of different stages:

- Sharingan (Increases power with age/3 commas = maturity)
- Mangekyo Sharingan (Unlock = Kill a close friend/family member) (Blindness over time)
- Time Erase (Kasashi's Mangekyo Sharingan)
- Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan (Perfect vision/Incredible Power)
- Amaterasu (Invincible Fire Attack)
- Tsukuyomi (Illusion Technique)
- Mind Control (Shisui Uchiha 'Mental Genjustu')
- Copying Ability (Endless library of techniques) (See opponents techniques/Mimic opponent)
- Susano'o (Giant Skeleton/Invincible Sword 'Totsuka Blade'/Invincible Shield 'Yata Mirror')
- The Blade and Mirror were found by Itachi, by unknown means - Teleportation
- Intangibility (Madara Uchiha)
- Izanagi (Dream/Illusion Technique)
- Sharingan+Rinnegan Techniques
- Mangekyo/Eternal Mangekyo

And it varies for each user in shape and appearances:

- Sasuke Uchiha - Six-Sided Star Shape (Mangekyo) Six-Sided Cyclone (Eternal)
- Itachi Uchiha - Three-Sided Cyclone
- Kakashi Hatake - Bizarre Three-Sided and Curved Cyclone
- Madara Uchiha - Izuna Uchiha - Stange Opened Circle with Three Squarish-Openings
- Shisui Uchiha - Four Sided Throwing Star

But the Byakugan stays the same and every member has the same one.

So it makes me curious, why doesn't Byakugan have a second stage?

Comment: You can't compare the two dōjutsu in terms of stages. It is completely different eyes. But as far as I know, Byakugan has only one stage while Sharingan has 5.

Comment: It is speculated that Toneri Ootsutsuki, the main villain in The Last: Naruto the Movie, will have a second stage Byakugan dojutsu. We'll just have to wait and see.

Comment: [The Next Level Byakugan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Toneri_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)

Comment: [Related question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/252/49)

Answer (score 3):

There is a "second stage" of the Byakugan, called [**Tenseigan**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tenseigan). And it has its own Chakra Mode, which is said to be on par with the Naruto's Nine-Tails Chakra Mode.

When the Byakugan is combined with the chakra of an Ōtsutsuki clan member, it evolves into the Tenseigan. The only known wielders are:

- Hamura Ōtsutsuki
- Toneri Ōtsutsuki

[image]

The Tenseigan has abilities similar to the Rinnegan.

> The Tenseigan allows the user to control both attractive and repulsive forces, similar to the Rinnegan. Additionally, it also grants the wielder Tenseigan Chakra Mode, which in turn gives the user an increase in speed, power, strength, durability, and reflexes. It also grants its user Truth-Seeking Balls, thus granting the user all five nature transformations and Yin–Yang Release.
>
> <sub>source: [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tenseigan)</sub>

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for a better notion on how to write a good answer. Link only answers are discouraged. Please try to include some details of what's in the link, should it go down, we'd be left with nothing but a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

In the anime, before the events of Naruto the last movie, the byakugan were the origional eyes of the otsutski clan: the precursors to all supernatural powers in the narutoverse. Kaguya was able to obtain the rnnesharingan, which simultaneously gave her both the rinnegan and sharingan, as a third eye while her natural white eyes mutated into the byakugan. The byakugan, at least by my standards before the conception of the tenseigan, were evolved from the otsutski clans natural white eyes while the sharingan and rinnegan were mutations caused by consuming the chakra fruit which most likely gave the wilder greater power than they already possessed. This probrobly evolved their natural physicality, eyes, but also gave them greater ocular power only obtainable by eating the shinju fruit: sharingan and rennegan. also, the tenseigan was most likely added post the events of the main story line to elevate the powers of Hamura to be on par with his brother so they would be deamed with the same amount of power.